# What is the largest atom with a reliable configuration-interaction (CI) calculation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, computational-physics, molecules

The simplest approximation for calculating the ground state of an atom is the Hartree-Fock approximation.

To get accurate result for the ground state energy, one has to do [configuration-interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_interaction) (CI). But then the dimension of the Hilbert space is huge.

So, so far, which atom is the largest one with a reliable CI calculation?

Comment: CI is widely applied to systems larger than a single atom. For example, a [$C_{10}$ carbon cluster](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/93/12/10.1063/1.459223). Or are you only interested in full CI?

Comment: full CI, only for a single atom